# LaTeX NiceMatrix: Error when using large matrices with Block-Command

Tags: arrays, matrix, latex, block

First of all, hey guys and thanks - after years of finding good answers on StackOverflow, I finally created an account to ask my first question :-)

The problem occurs when using the NiceMatrix-Package with the \Block-Command. It seems like there is a problem, if the matrix-indicies that the block covers exceed 10.

First of all, a working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC|CCC|CCCCC}[first-row,first-col]
      & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k \\
    a & \Block{3-3}{A} & & & \Block{3-3}{B} & & & \Block{3-3}{C} & & & & \\ % does compile
    b & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    c & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    d & \Block{3-3}{D} & & & \Block{3-3}{E} & & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    e & & & & & & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    f & & & & & & & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    g & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Block{3-3}{F} & & & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    h & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    i & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Not working:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC|CCC|CCCCC}[first-row,first-col]
      & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k \\
    a & \Block{3-3}{A} & & & \Block{3-3}{B} & & & \Block{3-5}{C} & & & & \\ % does not compile
    b & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    c & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    d & \Block{3-3}{D} & & & \Block{3-3}{E} & & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    e & & & & & & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    f & & & & & & & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    g & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Block{3-3}{F} & & & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    h & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    i & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Of course, the matrix C should be the size 3-5 instead of 3-3 to cover the empty space inside the matrix. But **after replacing** "\Block{3-3}{C}" with "\Block{3-5}{C}" (that is the only difference between the two examples), I get the **following error message**:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named `nm-1-col-21' is known. \end{bNiceArray}
```

I would be really happy, if there's a work-around or similar for that.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Log file says...

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.19)  20 MAR 2020 12:48
entering extended mode
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen135
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen136
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count175
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count176
\leftroot@=\count177
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count178
\DOTSCASE@=\count179
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box45
\strutbox@=\box46
\big@size=\dimen137
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count180
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count181
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count182
\dspbrk@lvl=\count183
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count184
\column@=\count185
\maxfields@=\count186
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen138
\alignsep@=\dimen139
\tagshift@=\dimen140
\tagwidth@=\dimen141
\totwidth@=\dimen142
\lineht@=\dimen143
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks19
\inpenc@posthook=\toks20

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\latin1.def"
File: latin1.def 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/nicematrix\nicematrix.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks21
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen144
\Gin@req@width=\dimen145
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks22
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen146
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen147

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box47
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex")
Package: pgfrcs 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks23
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks24

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks25
))
\pgf@x=\dimen148
\pgf@y=\dimen149
\pgf@xa=\dimen150
\pgf@ya=\dimen151
\pgf@xb=\dimen152
\pgf@yb=\dimen153
\pgf@xc=\dimen154
\pgf@yc=\dimen155
\pgf@xd=\dimen156
\pgf@yd=\dimen157
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count187
\c@pgf@countb=\count188
\c@pgf@countc=\count189
\c@pgf@countd=\count190
\t@pgf@toka=\toks26
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks27
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks28
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count191
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count192
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count193
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen158
\pgfmath@count=\count194
\pgfmath@box=\box48
\pgfmath@toks=\toks29
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks30
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks31
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count195
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen159
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@picminy=\dimen161
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen163
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen164
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen165
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen166
\pgf@xx=\dimen167
\pgf@xy=\dimen168
\pgf@yx=\dimen169
\pgf@yy=\dimen170
\pgf@zx=\dimen171
\pgf@zy=\dimen172
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen173
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen174
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen175
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen176
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfpic=\box49
\pgf@hbox=\box50
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box51
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count196
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen177
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen178
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen179
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen180
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen181
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@max=\dimen182
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count197
\pgf@shadingcount=\count198
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box52
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex"
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.
tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box53
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2020-02-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count199
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2020-02-14 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: nicematrix 2020/03/15 v3.13 Mathematical matrices with PGF/TikZ

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen183
\ar@mcellbox=\box55
\extrarowheight=\dimen184
\NC@list=\toks32
\extratabsurround=\skip52
\backup@length=\skip53
\ar@cellbox=\box56
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2020-02-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count266
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count267
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count268
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count269
)
\g__nicematrix_env_int=\count270
\g__nicematrix_NiceMatrixBlock_int=\count271
\l__nicematrix_columns_width_dim=\dimen185
\l__nicematrix_inter_dots_dim=\dimen186
\l__nicematrix_xdots_shorten_dim=\dimen187
\l__nicematrix_radius_dim=\dimen188
\l__nicematrix_save_iRow_int=\count272
\l__nicematrix_save_jCol_int=\count273
\l__nicematrix_x_initial_dim=\dimen189
\l__nicematrix_y_initial_dim=\dimen190
\l__nicematrix_x_final_dim=\dimen191
\l__nicematrix_y_final_dim=\dimen192
\l_tmpc_dim=\dimen193
\l_tmpd_dim=\dimen194
\l__nicematrix_first_row_int=\count274
\l__nicematrix_first_col_int=\count275
\l__nicematrix_last_row_int=\count276
\l__nicematrix_last_col_int=\count277
\l__nicematrix_left_margin_dim=\dimen195
\l__nicematrix_right_margin_dim=\dimen196
\g__nicematrix_width_last_col_dim=\dimen197
\g__nicematrix_width_first_col_dim=\dimen198
\l__nicematrix_extra_left_margin_dim=\dimen199
\l__nicematrix_extra_right_margin_dim=\dimen256
)
No file document.aux.
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count278
\scratchdimen=\dimen257
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count279
\nofMParguments=\count280
\everyMPshowfont=\toks33
\MPscratchCnt=\count281
\MPscratchDim=\dimen258
\MPnumerator=\count282
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count283
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks34
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\g__nicematrix_max_cell_width_dim=\dimen259
\l__nicematrix_cell_box=\box58
\c@iRow=\count284
\c@jCol=\count285
\g__nicematrix_row_total_int=\count286
\g__nicematrix_col_total_int=\count287
\g__nicematrix_last_vdotted_col_int=\count288
\l__nicematrix_left_delim_dim=\dimen260
\l__nicematrix_right_delim_dim=\dimen261
\l__nicematrix_the_array_box=\box59
\g__nicematrix_dp_row_zero_dim=\dimen262
\g__nicematrix_ht_row_zero_dim=\dimen263
\g__nicematrix_ht_row_one_dim=\dimen264
\g__nicematrix_dp_ante_last_row_dim=\dimen265
\g__nicematrix_ht_last_row_dim=\dimen266
\g__nicematrix_dp_last_row_dim=\dimen267
\g__nicematrix_ddots_int=\count289
\g__nicematrix_iddots_int=\count290
\g__nicematrix_delta_x_one_dim=\dimen268
\g__nicematrix_delta_y_one_dim=\dimen269
\g__nicematrix_delta_x_two_dim=\dimen270
\g__nicematrix_delta_y_two_dim=\dimen271
\l__nicematrix_initial_i_int=\count291
\l__nicematrix_initial_j_int=\count292
\l__nicematrix_final_i_int=\count293
\l__nicematrix_final_j_int=\count294


! Package pgf Error: No shape named `nm-1-col-21' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 \end{bNiceArray}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

[1

{C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(document.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11555 strings out of 481522
 236995 string characters out of 2922323
 493680 words of memory out of 3000000
 26653 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 535748 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 52i,13n,56p,412b,559s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb><C:/Program Fi
les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 31412 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 21 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me with both texlive 2019 and texlive 2020. Can you show your .log file?

Comment: Thanks for your replay!

Yes, it should compile fine! Now try to replace "\Block{3-3}{C}" with "\Block{3-5}{C}" to get the error message.

Comment: I edited the question to have a not-working example.

Comment: Your "non-working" example compiles fine for me. I would need the .log file to see if maybe some package of yours is outdated.

Comment: Thanks. I attached the log-file content.

Comment: Thanks! I can now reproduce your problem with nicematrix v3.13. With nicematrix v.3.11 it worked fine. I'm looking further into it

Comment: mmm, between 3.11 and 3.12 the name of the tikz nodes created by nicematrix changed. I suspect your problem might be connected to that. I suggest to get in contact with the package author to inquire if this is a bug. You can find the email address in the package documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will do so. Until a fix, it is possible to manually downgrade to the working version? (using TexStudio and MikTexPackage Manager)

Comment: As a temporary workaround you could download https://pastebin.com/raw/MZ4JfjbH and save it as `nicematrix.sty` in the same folder as your .tex document

Comment: Is there a way to upvote, contribute you or another way to thank you via Stackoverflow?

Comment: To hear that it's working is enough thank :) (if you hear back from the author, could you please write a short answer that summarizes what they suggest as a solution? This way other users with the same problem can benefit from the information)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, this was a bug in the package `nicematrix` and it has been corrected in the version 3.14 of `nicematrix` (I'm the author of this extension).